# GETTING THE ERROR 401 Unauthorized with Google Calendar API V3

Tags: api, insert, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to insert some events into my calendar with API V3 but I get this error every time I run it:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at GoogleAdapter.AddRecurringEvents(GoogleAdapter.java:186)
    at Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Any help ?

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with your authentication.  Can you post some code?

Comment: i just fix it thank you, im trying to test with my code not my token, thanks*

Comment: how did u fix this issue @user3445864